# MySQL return most recent row for unique ID

Tags: mysql

I want to make a query that returns the most recent sales order for a customer.

I have a Customers and and an Orders table that are joined on ID, and i've made the following query to return all values. Can anyone help me modify it to only return the latest value for each ID? Orders.created_at is formatted like so yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

```
SELECT Customers.ID, Customers.Name, Customers."Sales Responsible US", Customers."Sales     Responsible", Customers."Website", ISNULL(Orders.row_invoiced, '-1'), Orders.status, Orders.created_at
FROM "Customers"
LEFT JOIN Orders
On Customers.ID=Orders.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ::

```
   SELECT Customers.ID, 
Customers.Name, 
Customers."Sales Responsible US", 
Customers."Sales     Responsible", 
Customers."Website", 
IFNULL(Orders.row_invoiced, '-1'), 
Orders.status, MAX(Orders.created_at)
    FROM "Customers"
    LEFT JOIN Orders On Customers.ID=Orders.customer_id

    group by Orders.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting, MAX on orders created. Group by Customer id. (typo)

PS: I am on mobile. do not have code snippets format.

Answer (score 0):

I would join everything you already have to subquery that gets latest (`max(created_at)`) order date for each customer (`group by customer_id`).

```
SELECT Customers.ID, 
    Customers.Name, 
    Customers."Sales Responsible US", 
    Customers."Sales     Responsible", 
    Customers."Website", 
    ISNULL(Orders.row_invoiced, '-1'), 
    Orders.status, 
    Orders.created_at
FROM "Customers"
LEFT JOIN Orders On Customers.ID=Orders.customer_id
left join (
    select customer_id, max(created_at) as created_at
    from Orders 
    group by customer_id
) as t on Orders.customer_id = t.customer_id and Orders.created_at = t.created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hope this will do ur requirement

```
SELECT Customers.ID, Customers.Name, Customers."Sales Responsible US", Customers."Sales     Responsible", Customers."Website", ISNULL(Orders.row_invoiced, '-1'), Orders.status, MAX(Orders.created_at)
FROM "Customers"
LEFT JOIN Orders
On Customers.ID=Orders.customer_id 
GROUP BY Orders.customer_id
```